# Filter unique values from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

How can I use Array.filter() to return unique `id` with `name` ?

My scenario is slightly different than the solutions I have researched in that I have an array of objects. Every example I find contains a flat array of single values.

```js
data=[
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Jordan" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Bob" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "John" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Rhoda" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Harry" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Joe" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Jake" },
];
```

```js
var unique = data.filter(
function (x, i) {
   return data[i].id.indexOf(x.id) === i
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is better to achieve what you are looking for:

```js
var data=[
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Jordan" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Bob" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "John" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Rhoda" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Harry" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Joe" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Jake" },
];
var resArr = [];
data.forEach(function(item){
  var i = resArr.findIndex(x => x.name == item.name);
  if(i <= -1){
    resArr.push({id: item.id, name: item.name});
  }
});
console.log(resArr);
```

If you really want to use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) try the following way:

```js
var data=[
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Jordan" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "Bob" },
{id: 555, name: "Sales", person: "John" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Rhoda" },
{id: 777, name: "Accounts Payable", person: "Harry" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Joe" },
{id: 888, name: "IT", person: "Jake" },
];
var resArr = [];
data.filter(function(item){
  var i = resArr.findIndex(x => x.name == item.name);
  if(i <= -1){
    resArr.push({id: item.id, name: item.name});
  }
  return null;
});
console.log(resArr);
```

Comment: Yup, that's it ! I was going for a for loop, but I think filter is best.

Comment: I don't understand why SO jumps to conclusions so quickly re: with a duplicate answer remark. I had searched, but hadn't found the best solution for my scenario.

Comment: I think that forEach would be better since this approach does not actually use the filter function, since it does not return anything inside the function.

Comment: data = data.reduce((items, item) => items.find(x => x.name === item.name) ? [...items] : [...items, item], [])

Comment: @ChristopherKiessling I like this.  Any reason to do [...items] instead of just items in the first branch of the ternary?

Comment: @jinglesthula my bad, use just items in the first ternary branch

Comment: hmm is this how `filter` should be used since it doesnt use the returned array of filter