# Loop over objects to get only the unique keys

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have an array of objects:

```
let array1 = [
  { age: 20, name: "bob" }, 
  { age: 24, name: "Mike" },
  { age: 20, name: "Penny" },
  { age: 24, name: "Jeff" },
  { age: 25, name: "Mary" }
];
```

Trying to find an example of a forLoop or forEach that will loop over the array of objects and return only the unique age keys(`[20, 24, 25]`) that I will push to another array.

The expect results values would be:

```
[20, 24, 25]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter unique values from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374112/filter-unique-values-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: May you provide the expected result? it's quite unclear what you mean by `and return only the unique age keys that I will push to another array.`

Answer (score 4):

Using es6 sets this can be accomplished in a single line.

`let res = [...new Set(array1.map(e => e.age))];`

Explained:

`array1.map(e => e.age)` will return a copy of the original array by returning the .age values only, hence the result will be: `[20,24,20,24,25]`.

`new Set(array1.map(e => e.age))` will make a unique set from the above array, hence it will be a `Set` instance, which will **automatically remove duplicates**.

`...new Set` <-- the spread operator (`...`) will convert the above set to an array. The corresponding result will be, so, `[20,24,25]`.

https://jsfiddle.net/6ozdqsuw/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to end up with a standard array I'd recommend getting all instances of age, then convert to a Set and back again.

First get just the entries at the age key to get an array of ages.

```
const allAges = originalArray.map(({ age }) => age)
```

Then create a set from the age:

```
const ageSet = new Set(allAges)
```

Then convert back to an array of you want:

```
const uniqueAges = [...ageSet]
```

If you want it in one line:

```
const uniqueAges = [...new Set(originalArray.map(({ age }) => age))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
let result = [];
array1.forEach(e=>{
    if (result.indexOf(e.age) === -1) {
        result.push(e.age)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works.  I have an understanding of what you are doing by pushing to two arrays.  Can you explain the function or actually write it out?

Comment: It loops through the original array and checks if the value for the `age` property exists in the `result` array (its `indexOf()` will return `-1` if it doesn't). If not, it will push this value to `result`.

Comment: Thanks I'm not good with arrow functions.  Thanks why I was like can we write this out lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "unique"
but, if you use filter, you can get a new array with only age keys:

```
let filtered = array1.map(elem => elem.age)
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is exactly the thing the ES6 `Set` was made for!

Using a `Set`, you can add any elements you like, but they will only add to the set if they are not already in it.

```js
let array1 = [
    {
        name: "bob",
        age: 20,
    }, 
    {
        name: "Mike",
        age: 24,
    },
    {
        name: "Penny",
        age: 20,
    },
    {
        name: "Jeff",
        age: 24,
    },
    {
        name: "Mary",
        age: 25,
    },
]

let ages = new Set()
array1.forEach(user => {
  ages.add(user.age)
}) 

//ages = Set [ 20, 24, 25 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off of my understanding of the question, this is a functional solution using built in Array iterator methods.
`map` returns an array of just the ages (ie: `[20, 24, 20, 24, 25]`) and `filter` removes duplicates.

```js
let array1 = [
    {
        name: "bob",
        age: 20,
    }, 
    {
        name: "Mike",
        age: 24,
    },
    {
        name: "Penny",
        age: 20,
    },
    {
        name: "Jeff",
        age: 24,
    },
    {
        name: "Mary",
        age: 25,
    },
]

console.log(
  array1
    .map(({age}) => age)
    .filter((age, i, arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(age) === i)
)
```