# How to get unique values from object array

Tags: javascript

I have a mapped an array object, now I need to get unique values from that array's children.

```
const arr=[
            {
              name: 'name1',
              functions:{
                0:{
                  name:'some1',
                  property: 'string'
                },
                1:{
                  name:'some1',
                  property: 'string'
                },
                2:{
                  name:'some3',
                  property: 'number'
                }
              }
            },
          ]


<div>
          {
              arr.map((item, index) => {
                  let ars=[]
                  //console.log(item.functions)
                  for(const key in item.functions){                
                    if(ars.indexOf(item.functions[key])>1){
                        ars.push(item.functions[key])
                    }
                  }
                  console.log(ars)
              return <div key={index}>
                <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                {
                    ars.map((i)=>(
                        <p>{i.name}</p>
                    ))
                }

              </div>
          })
          }
          </div>
```

I need to get values like this:
some1
some3

So I need to get only one name from property string. And for number there is only one name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter unique values from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374112/filter-unique-values-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: I don't understand what is the expected output. Can you add to your question what you want the code to return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for `property`. If a `property` hasn't been added yet, add the `name` for the property to the array.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'name1',
  functions: {
    0: {
      name: 'some1',
      property: 'string'
    },
    1: {
      name: 'some2',
      property: 'string'
    },
    2: {
      name: 'some3',
      property: 'number'
    }
  }
}]

const propertySet = new Set,
      names = []

for (const { functions } of arr) {
  Object.values(functions).forEach(o => {
    if (!propertySet.has(o.property)) {
      names.push(o.name);
      propertySet.add(o.property)
    }
  })
}

console.log(names)
```

Comment: I need to get output like this: some1, some3

Comment: @Saban This gives you an array of unique names. You can `map` through it and create the `div` as you're doing

Comment: @Saban why is `some2` not included in the expected output?

Comment: I need to filter array by property names, so I want to get some1 and not some2 because property name (string) is the same.

Comment: Not correct answer, he needs to print names based on unique properties. Since some2 and some3 has same property value only one should be in output

Comment: @user8672473 updated. OP's original question was unclear

Comment: @3limin4t0r If I understand correctly, OP doesn't want to get unique names. OP wants to get names for each unique `property`. Earlier version of OP's question had a different input. Check their comment in the thread. *"I want to get `some1` and not `some2` because `property` name is the same*"

Comment: @adiga Yep just saw it after looking at the code for a second time. So removed my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

If uniqueness based upon the string representation of the value of `property` is enough and the value of `name` is always truthy you can use the following code:

```js
const arr = [{name: 'name1', functions: {0: {name: 'some1', property: 'string'}, 1: {name: 'some2', property: 'string'}, 2: {name: 'some3', property: 'number'}}}];

let lookup = {};
arr.forEach(obj => {
  Object.values(obj.functions).forEach(func => {
    lookup[func.property] || (lookup[func.property] = func.name);
  });
});

console.log(Object.values(lookup));
```

**Note:** This solution sees `property: 123` and `property: "123"` as the same value, since the string representation is used. If the following is an option `name: ""`, `name: null`, etc. then the first truthy `name` is used, if there is no truthy name present the last occurrence of `name` is used instead.